# Unable to link javascript in cake php (defalut.ctp)

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have the following code in my default.ctp (projects/customer/lib/Cake/View/Layouts/default.ctp), in the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/developer/workarea/projects/customer/app/webroot/js/jquery.autoSuggest.packed.js"></script>
```

But the js file not available to the browser: clicking on the link in view source to view the js file produces the following error:

```
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /home/developer/workarea/projects/customer/app/webroot/js/jquery.autoSuggest.packed.js was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

But the js file is accessible by directly entering its url in the browser.

Comment: `/home/developer/workarea/projects/customer/app/webroot/js/jquery.autoSuggest.packed.js` is it a path from the root of the file system or from the root of the web server?

Comment: @cheery its a path from root of the web server ie folder www=>projects

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. if `projects` is a root of the www server then why do you write `/home/developer/workarea`?

Comment: @cheery newbie in programing kindly advice

Comment: Path to js script should be from the root of the server. Probably you should have `/customer/app/webroot/js/jquery.autoSuggest.pa‌​cked.js` or `/js/jquery.autoSuggest.pa‌​cked.js`

Comment: @Cheery tried both the url but same response

Comment: put php file in the server root with the following code `<?php phpinfo();?>`, call it from browser, check the path to the server root (`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`) and convert your path to the js file correspondingly.

Comment: @Cheery Thanks for responding to this simple questions , it worked

Answer (score 0):

why you don'try :

```
<?php $this->Html->script('jquery.autoSuggest.packed.js');?>
```